# Obter propriedades de uma classe com condição. C#

Tags: c#, reflexão

Gostaria de obter as propriedades do meu objeto Pais, mas não gostaria de pegar a propriedade (Estados) da minha classe País. Tentei da forma que está na classe "Teste" e não consegui devido a não saber o Tipo que é o IEnumerable.

Teria alguma outra forma de não trazer apenas esta propriedade realizando uma condição genérica, pois não posso colocar o nome da property, porque esse é um processo que vai ser usado para todas minhas classe de entidade, e preciso ignorar todas properties que seja do tipo IEnumerable.

```
public partial class Teste
{
   Pais pais = new Pais();
   PropertyInfo[] properties = pais .GetType().GetProperties().Select(x => 
   x.PropertyType != typeof(IEnumerable<T>));
}    

public partial class Pais : EntityBase
{
    public Pais() : base() 
    {
        this.Estados = new HashSet<Estado>();
    }

    public override string TableName { get { return "PAIS"; } }
    public override int Handle { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Sigla { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Estado> Estados { get; set; }
    public override DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }
    public override string UsuarioCadastro { get; set; }
    public override DateTime? DataAlteracao { get; set; }
    public override string UsuarioAlteracao { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Tá, mas qual é o critério do que deve pegar ou não. Pela pergunta não tem como saber. Parece que o nome  `Estados` não é o critério, então qual é? Qual o resultado esperado?

Comment: Depois eu reabro, o pessoal está chutando coisas que não dá para saber se é isto mesmo, tanto que cada um dá uma solução que não produz o mesmo resultado a não ser por coincidência.

Comment: Ela colocou sim o tipo que quer a sua exclusão é IEnumerable ...

Comment: Pra mim esta pergunta está bem clara, não tem nenhum motivo pra ser marcada como pendente...

Comment: Pra mim não está. Está ambígua, quando esse problema for resolvido podemos reabrir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa verificar se a propriedade implementa a interface base `IEnumerable`

```
pais
.GetType()
.GetProperties()
.Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof (string) || 
       !typeof (System.Collections.IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(x.PropertyType))
.ToArray();
```

O IEnumerable é a interface mais base que tem, ou seja , qualquer coleção, lista, e arrays a implementam e consequentemente a string também implementa, pois a string é uma cadeia de caracteres, ou seja, um **array** de `char`

No código eu pego todas as propriedades que não forem string ou não implementar a interface IEnumerable.

Comment: Isso mesmo amigo, deu certo, era isso mesmo que eu precisava.

Comment: @NicolaBogar Dar certo é diferente de funcionar sempre, pode funcionar nesse caso, mas em comentário afora apagado está escrito que quer algo genérico, o que neste caso pode não funcionar. Eu sequer sei, porque a pergunta não esclarece isso. A minha resposta seria diferente das outras 3 postadas e talvez fosse o que deseja para todas situações que precisa. Não temos como saber. Pra falar a verdade dependendo do que precisa tem uma solução absurdamente mais simples que isso, mas não dá para saber com o que está na pergunta.

Comment: @bigown, vamos colaborar com o site, não é só as suas respostas que é a correta, na programação existem diversos caminhos que chegam no mesmo lugar se a  falou que deu certo, está certo, caso contrário e se você não tivesse fechado a pergunta sem motivo, você poderia por a sua resposta e ela (a nicola) escolheria a sua se estivesse certo.

Comment: @bigown, meu problema é o seguinte: Tenho a Classe Pais, que nela tem uma propriedade IEnumerable<Estado>, nesse caso, eu estou pegando as properties desta classe, mas eu desejo pegar todas que não seja IEnumerable<T>, porque em outras minha classes também terá por exemplo uma propriedade IEnumerable<Cidade> na

Comment: @TiagoS eu não falei que a sua está errada, falei que a pergunta não deixa claro o que é necessário. Então vamos colaborar com o site só respondendo algo que não tem ambiguidades. Diversos caminhos que dão resultados diferentes um deles está certo, os outros estão errados. Pode ser que o seu esteja certo, mas não tem como saber. Pode ser que nesse teste inicial deu o resultado esperado, mas pode não resolver quando for fazer algo diferente disto. Eu só quero que a pergunta ajude todos, aqui não é um fórum.

Comment: Continuação -> minha classe Estado. E esse processo que estou pegando as properties ela é realizada de maneira genérica, por isso gostaria que fosse algo mais genérico, tipo, não pegar as propriedades que implementam ICollection. Preciso disso porque essas classes representam tabelas do meu banco de dados, e não existe esse campo Estados na tabela paises, essa coleção foi criada apenas para auxilio, tipo um EntityAssociation. Não sei se ficou bem claro, consegue compreender ?

Comment: Não é assim que funciona, colocar um monte de chute e uma pessoa escolhe quem teve mais sorte, o site nunca funcionou assim.

Comment: @NicolaBogar Não use os comentários para esclarecer, edite a pergunta para ficar claro.